# does python have a package or function to train neural network with stacked autoencoder like deepnet in R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I have a neural network that I am using in Python with Keras / tensorflow. I'm trying to get used to using Python.

In R there [is this function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deepnet/versions/0.2/topics/sae.dnn.train) that pre-trains a neural network with a stacked autoencoder from deepnet. I can't seem to find a similar function or package in Python. Do I need to write my own function of does Python / Keras have such a function as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find this implementation in python using the below function.

Configuration:

```
n_hidden_layer   = 3
n_hidden_unit    = 1000
neuron           = Neurons.Sigmoid()
param_key_prefix = "ip-layer"
corruption_rates = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
pretrain_epoch   = 15
finetune_epoch   = 1000
batch_size       = 100
momentum         = 0.0
pretrain_lr      = 0.001
finetune_lr      = 0.1

param_keys       = ["$param_key_prefix-$i" for i = 1:n_hidden_layer] 

data_layer = HDF5DataLayer(name="train-data", source="data/train.txt",
    batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=@windows ? false : true)
rename_layer = IdentityLayer(bottoms=[:data], tops=[:ip0])
hidden_layers = [
  InnerProductLayer(name="ip-$i", param_key=param_keys[i],
      output_dim=n_hidden_unit, neuron=neuron,
      bottoms=[symbol("ip$(i-1)")], tops=[symbol("ip$i")])
  for i = 1:n_hidden_layer
]
```

Pre-training:

```
  ae_data_layer = SplitLayer(bottoms=[symbol("ip$(i-1)")], tops=[:orig_data, :corrupt_data])
  corrupt_layer = RandomMaskLayer(ratio=corruption_rates[i], bottoms=[:corrupt_data])

  encode_layer  = copy(hidden_layers[i], bottoms=[:corrupt_data])
  recon_layer   = TiedInnerProductLayer(name="tied-ip-$i", tied_param_key=param_keys[i],tops=[:recon], bottoms=[symbol("ip$i")])
  recon_loss_layer = SquareLossLayer(bottoms=[:recon, :orig_data]) 

  da_layers = [data_layer, rename_layer, ae_data_layer, corrupt_layer,
      hidden_layers[1:i-1]..., encode_layer, recon_layer, recon_loss_layer]
  da = Net("Denoising-Autoencoder-$i", backend, da_layers)
  println(da)

  # freeze all but the layers for auto-encoder
  freeze_all!(da)
  unfreeze!(da, "ip-$i", "tied-ip-$i")  

  base_dir = "pretrain-$i"
  method = SGD()
  pretrain_params  = make_solver_parameters(method, max_iter=div(pretrain_epoch*60000,batch_size),
      regu_coef=0.0, mom_policy=MomPolicy.Fixed(momentum),
      lr_policy=LRPolicy.Fixed(pretrain_lr), load_from=base_dir)
  solver = Solver(method, pretrain_params)

  add_coffee_break(solver, TrainingSummary(), every_n_iter=1000)
  add_coffee_break(solver, Snapshot(base_dir), every_n_iter=3000)
  solve(solver, da)

  destroy(da)
```

For more information and finetuning, you can refer to this [documentation](https://mochajl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/mnist-sDA.html).